# Is there a way to clear the filterable dropdown field every time I click on the dropdown button of the gooey parser widget?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have an application that is using gooey parser library to offer graphical user interface. On of the widgets in a subparser of this application is a timezone selector. The timezone selector offers a filterable dropdown with time zone options from US, Canada, and UTC. When a timzone is selected from the dropdown list, the field is populated with the string that identifies the timezone. However, right now, to change the timezone, I have to delete the entire string in the filterable dropdown field before seeing all the options to choose from again. Would it be possible to clear the field value to have nothing as soon as the dropdown button is clicked so that the existing value from there goes away and I can see all the options again.
Here is the code snippet that I am using:

```
# Select from US, Canada, and UTC timezones
    timezone_choices = filter(lambda tz: "US/" in tz or "Canada/" in tz or tz == "Etc/UTC", zoneinfo.available_timezones())
    device_group.add_argument(
        "--timezone",
        required=False,
        help="Timezone of the device, assumed to be this computer's timezone",
        choices=timezone_choices,
        metavar="Timezone",
        widget="FilterableDropdown",
        gooey_options = {
            "placeholder" : "Use System Timezone (Default)",
        }
    )
```

Here is the picture of a populated filterable dropdown list (after selecting a time zone):
[The filterable dropdown list populated with a value. Need to delete all the characters before seeing all the options back again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckV2m.png)

I tried having callback argument within add_argument function and created a function that basically clears the widget field by placing "" every time the dropdown button is clicked. However, I get an error that "callback" is not an expected argument.

Comment: "Gooey" is spelled "GUI"